# Is it possible to use a dropdown menu as navigation?

Tags: kotlin, drop-down-menu, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying to use a dropdown menu as my navigation for an app I am building. However I get an error inside the onClick function of the dropdown menu items saying "unsolved reference".

I have tried following [this](https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/android-basics-compose-unit-4-pathway-2) course but that way didn't work for me. It uses regular buttons to navigate, but i want to use a dropdown. I tried Googling the error and tried a few possible solutions but none of them worked for me.

Below is the code of the dropdown menu

```
@Composable
fun TopAppBarDropdownMenu() {
    val expanded = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    
    Box(
        Modifier
            .wrapContentSize(Alignment.TopEnd)
    ) {
        IconButton(
            onClick = {
                expanded.value = true
            }
        ) {
            Icon(
                Icons.Filled.Menu,
                contentDescription = "Menu"
            )
        }
    }

    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded.value,
        onDismissRequest = { expanded.value = false}
    ) {
        DropdownMenuItem(
            text = {
                Text(text = stringResource(R.string.pagina_1))
            },
            onClick = {
                expanded.value = false
            }
        )

        Divider()

        DropdownMenuItem(
            text = {
                Text(text = stringResource(R.string.pagina_2))
            },
            onClick = {
                onNavigatePagina2()
                expanded.value = false
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the NavHost

```
@Composable
fun PresentTest(
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
) {
    val backStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentScreen = Pagina.valueOf(
        backStackEntry?.destination?.route ?: Pagina.Pagina1.name
    )
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            PresentTestAppBar(
                currentScreen = currentScreen
            )
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = Pagina.Pagina1.name,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            composable(route = Pagina.Pagina1.name) {
                Pagina1Screen(
                    onNavigatePagina2 = {
                        navController.navigate(Pagina.Pagina2.name)
                    }
                )
            }
            composable(route = Pagina.Pagina2.name) {
                Pagina2Screen(
                    onNavigatePagina1 = {
                        navController.navigate(Pagina.Pagina1.name)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `DropdownMenuItem`, the `onNavigatePagina2()` function is not defined.

In your NavHost, you are passing the `onNavigatePagina2()` function to the `Pagina1Screen`. So in the `Pagina1Screen` Composable, you would be able to call the function. But you are not passing it to the `TopAppBarDropdownMenu` Composable, so you can't call it there.

You can pass the function to your `TopAppBarDropdownMenu` to make it available there.
First, change your `PresentTest` Composable as follows:

```
//...
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        PresentTestAppBar(
            currentScreen = currentScreen,
            onNavigatePagina2 = {
                navController.navigate(Pagina.Pagina2.name)
            }
        )
    }
) {
    //...
}
```

Then update the `PresentTestAppBar` Composable as follows:

```
@Composable
PresentTestAppBar(currentScreen: Pagina, onNavigatePagina2: () -> Unit) {
    //...
    actions = { TopAppBarDropdownMenu(onNavigatePagina2) }
    //...
}
```

Finally, modify your `TopAppBarDropdownMenu` Composable, and then your code should work:

```
@Composable
fun TopAppBarDropdownMenu(onNavigatePagina2: () -> Unit) {
   
    //... now, you can call the onNavigatePagina2() function here

}
```

Comment: I apologize, @BenjyTex. I forgot to inlcude it, anyway here is the code for the dropdown menu:

`@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun PresentTestAppBar(
    currentScreen: Pagina
) {
    TopAppBar(
        title = {
            Text(text = stringResource(currentScreen.title))
        },
        actions = {
            TopAppBarDropdownMenu()
        }
    )
}`